# Something is overriding my emacs font size

Tags: emacs

In my `.emacs` file, I have `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 200)` as the last line.

When I start up emacs, I actually see the text flash briefly to this size, but then quickly get resized to the default size (height 110).

How can I discover what's overriding my font setting?

My OS is Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Update: I've tried removing everything from my `.emacs` file, and then using `M-x customize-face default` to make the font height 200, as suggested by @Drew. My `.emacs` file now looks like

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 200 :width normal :foundry "1ASC" :family "Liberation Mono")))))
```

However, I'm still seeing the same effect on startup. A brief flash of size 200 and the font getting resized by something after that.

Answer (score 0):

`set-face-attribute` with `nil` for the frame sets a face attribute for the frame that's selected when that function is invoked.  Don't use it in your init file unless you know which frame will be selected when it's invoked, and you want to change the face on that frame.

Either customize face `default` or customize `default-frame-alist` (its font, color, etc. parameters).  I suggest `M-x customize-face default`.  That affects face `default` in general - the default for all new frames.

Beyond that, it's possible that something in your init file is changing the font of the `default` face later on. When you do `M-x customize-face default` you can see what the latest value of the font attribute is.

If you think something in your init file is messing things up, bisect your init file to find it. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a block of code or (with `C-u`) uncomment a block of code.  Comment out 1/2 of your init file, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... till you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. I tried your suggestion but I'm seeing the same effect. I completely emptied out my `.emacs` file except for what was put there by customize.

Comment: I think that can happen on some platforms. You might also try customizing `initial-frame-alist` (the font part). There's an initial frame, which uses that alist, before `default-frame-alist` kicks in. The initial frame and its alist are only used during startup.

Comment: My `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist` are both `nil` according to `describe-variable`

The commands I tried `(set-face-attribute 'initial-frame-alist nil :height 200)
(set-face-attribute 'default-frame-alist nil :height 200)` didn't work, so I'll have to research more how the frame-alist works.

Comment: Try just customizing `initial-frame-alist` to do what you want, and test with an init file that just has only the Customize stuff (preferably only the setting for `initial-frame-alist`). (Back up your init file first, so you can easily restore it after testing.)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I found that desktop file (`~/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop`) was responsible for the same behavior. After cleaning it up, I was able to assign fonts via .Xresources file, in an attempt to avoid further fighting with emacs complexities. However I didn't clean the entire .emacs file, I still had `(desktop-save-mode 1)` in it, so maybe this is not an answer.